# Solrpy how to do pagination?

Tags: python, solr

Solrpy is a solr client for python. The basic use is:

```
s = solr.SolrConnection('http://localhost:8080/solr/bt')
rows = 20
results = s.query(q, rows=rows)
```

How to do pagination query?

Answer (score 0):

You can control pagination using the two parameters `start` and `rows`.

Example start=0&rows=20 would give the first 20 results and start=20&rows=20 would give the next 20 set of results.

Update

```
>>> response = c.query('test', rows=20)
>>> print response.results.start
 0
>>> for match in response:
...     print match['id'],
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
>>> response = response.next_batch()
>>> print response.results.start
 20
```

Comment: How to do pagination with Solrpy directly?